# Setting up Docker Compose and PHP 7.3

Tags: php, docker-compose, github-actions

I'm using `https://github.com/myoung34/docker-github-actions-runner` through `docker-compose.yml`. The following is my Docker Compose configuration.

**docker-compose.yml :**

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  runner:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: "Dockerfile-Runner"
    container_name: runner_name_custom
    links: 
        - mysql
    environment:
        REPO_URL: https://github.com/haidertm/tilemountain2
        RUNNER_NAME: tilemountain-runner-m2
        RUNNER_TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        RUNNER_WORKDIR: /tmp/runner/tilemountain_m2
        RUNNER_SCOPE: 'repo'
        LABELS: linux,x64,gpu,self-hosted
    security_opt:
      # needed on SELinux systems to allow docker container to manage other docker containers
      - label:disable
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    volumes:
      - '/tmp/runner:/tmp/runner'
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: 'mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
```

In `Dockerfile-Runner` file, i have following content.

```
FROM myoung34/github-runner:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y locales
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y sshpass
RUN apt-get install -y bzip2 && apt-get install -y rsync grsync

# Setting up locale
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

I want to have PHP-7.3 make available in docker container of GitHub runner.

For that I tried using `https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php`

I'm using in workflow file like this.

```
    - name: Setup PHP with PECL extension
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      env:
          runner: self-hosted
      with:
        php-version: '7.3'
        tools: pecl, composer, phpunit
        ini-values: post_max_size=256M, short_open_tag=On
        extensions: mbstring,PDO,gd,imagick,json,xsl,zip,grpc,xml,openssl,bcmath,fileinfo
```

But I am getting these warnings.

[image]

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so (librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dba.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so (libqdbm.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so (libc-client.so.2007e: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so (libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pspell.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so (libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'snmp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so (libnetsnmp.so.35: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so (libtidy.so.5deb1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so (libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so (libpgm-5.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so (libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so (libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so (librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dba.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so (libqdbm.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so (libc-client.so.2007e: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so (libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pspell.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so (libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'snmp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so (libnetsnmp.so.35: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so (libtidy.so.5deb1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so (libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so (libpgm-5.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so (libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so (libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

** (process:18958): WARNING **: 11:53:10.301: Error loading plugin: libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


** (process:18958): WARNING **: 11:53:10.302: Error loading plugin: libhunspell-1.7.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so (librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/amqp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dba.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so (libqdbm.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/dba.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so (libc-client.so.2007e: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/interbase.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so (libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_dblib.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so (libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_firebird.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pspell.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so (libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pspell.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'snmp.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so (libnetsnmp.so.35: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/snmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so (libtidy.so.5deb1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/tidy.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so (libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so (libpgm-5.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/zmq.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so (libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so (libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731//usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried going through the issues of its Git repository for related issues that could solve my problem.

I stumbled upon a similar problem there, where an issue got [resolved](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/issues/440#issuecomment-811999774), but I am still not clear how to implement that fix for my case.

```
https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/issues/440#issuecomment-811999774
```

There it's mentioned the configuration while using this command

```
act -P ubuntu-latest=shivammathur/node:focal
```

But how and from where this command needs to be executed? I could not find it in any documentation.

My GitHub actions workflow yml file is automatically hit whenever there is any pull request or push to master.

So how can I put this command and where to put it?

Answer (score 2):

Act is for testing GitHub Action workflows locally.
https://github.com/nektos/act

For the workflow, looks like you ran it without `runner: self-hosted` and then added the runner environment variable. Please start with a clean docker image and run setup-php with `runner: self-hosted`.

Also instead of using `myoung34/github-runner`, please use `ubuntu` or `shivammathur/node` as your base image as setup-php is tested with them.

Installing the GitHub actions runner should be easy in your Dockerfile, you can follow this [guide](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/wiki/Dockerized-self-hosted-runner-on-Linux) to do that.